# how could hide the predict progress bar

Tags: progress-bar, tensorflow2.0

[image]

when I use tensorflow==2.9 to predict the model , I got the progress bar, but I don't want to display this progress bar, how could hide this progress bar? It make me very angry.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, this behaviour has changed since `tensorflow` v2.9. In `v2.8` default value for `verbose=0`. However since `v2.9` it is set to `auto`. Have a look [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict) to understand different `verbose` options. So,

Simply use `model.predict(x, verbose=0)`

And it should fix it.

Comment: If you're using the model.train_on_batch method, how can you adjust the verbosity level?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this:

```
model.predict("input",verbose=None)
```

It works!

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the progress bar globally:

```py
tf.keras.utils.disable_interactive_logging()
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/is_interactive_logging_enabled